# WP_Query for products always returns empty

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a simple following logic:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('product'),
    'product_cat' => 280,
    'posts_per_page' => 3       
);


$category_posts = new WP_Query( $args );


if($category_posts->have_posts()):
    $result = '<div class="three-products">';

    while($category_posts->have_posts()):

    the_post();

        $result .= '<div class="one-product">'.the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' ).'</div>';
    endwhile;
        $result .= '</div>';

        wp_reset_postdata();

        return $result;

else:
     _e( 'There were no products matching your criteria.' );
endif;
```

I am sure that there are products in category 280, however have_posts always returns false.

If I comment that line out, it seems to end in infinite loop and does not load page at all.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Use a proper `tax_query`, your taxonomy syntax is incorrect, that is where your code is failing

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that? I have found some examples of tax_query, however I cannot seem to get it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arguments should look like this :

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'product', // No need for an array since you only query one post type
  'posts_per_page' => 3,
  'tax_query'=>array(      // The taxonomy query
      array(
        'taxonomy'  => 'product_cat',
        'field'     => 'term_id', // Can be omitted, default parameter, can also be 'slug' or 'name' (name should be avoided as @Pieter Goosen says)
        'terms'     => 280       // You can use an array to include multiples terms i.e. array(280,281)
      )
  )
);
```

It doesn't work because wordpress only handle native taxonomy (category), for custom taxonomies, [you must use a tax_query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters).

Comment: You can omit the `field` parameter here as its default is `term_id` ;-)

Comment: You are right ! Thought it would be more clear this way, going to do a little edit

Comment: Great. Just one note on the `field` parameter, you should avoid using the `name` value. Due to very bad sanitation in the `WP_Tax_Query` class, the term is not recognised and therefor your query fails. The last ticket I saw regarding this issue, it will not be fixed.